# how do I select xpath image without a class name using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

How do i select an image xpath without a classname. HTML code is like this

`<img alt="" class src="https://images.craigslist.org/00J0J_i9BI6mN6rKP_300x300.jpg">`

If I right click and copy xpath it gives me this `//*[@id="sortable-results"]/ul/li[1]/a/img` but when I use it in my code it has some error

In my code i use like this

```
 src = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/li[@class="result-row"]/a[@class="result-image gallery"]/img[@class=""]/@src')
```

but it returns me an `[]` when i `print(src)`

Full div

```
<li class="result-row" data-pid="7017735595">

        <a href="https://vancouver.craigslist.org/van/ele/d/vancouver-sealed-brand-new-in-box/7017735595.html" class="result-image gallery" data-ids="1:00J0J_i9BI6mN6rKP"><img alt="" class="" src="https://images.craigslist.org/00J0J_i9BI6mN6rKP_300x300.jpg">
                <span class="result-price">$35</span>
        </a>

    <p class="result-info">
        <span class="icon icon-star" role="button" title="save this post in your favorites list">
            <span class="screen-reader-text">favorite this post</span>
        </span>

            <time class="result-date" datetime="2019-11-11 00:52" title="Mon 11 Nov 12:52:25 AM">Nov 11</time>


        <a href="https://vancouver.craigslist.org/van/ele/d/vancouver-sealed-brand-new-in-box/7017735595.html" data-id="7017735595" class="result-title hdrlnk">Sealed - Brand New in Box - Google Home Mini</a>


        <span class="result-meta">
                <span class="result-price">$35</span>


                <span class="result-hood"> (Vancouver)</span>

                <span class="result-tags">
                    <span class="pictag">pic</span>
                </span>

                <span class="banish icon icon-trash" role="button">
                    <span class="screen-reader-text">hide this posting</span>
                </span>

            <span class="unbanish icon icon-trash red" role="button" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <a href="#" class="restore-link">
                <span class="restore-narrow-text">restore</span>
                <span class="restore-wide-text">restore this posting</span>
            </a>

        </span>
    </p>
</li>
```

Comment: can you share the whole div where your image is located? you can create an absolute path using xpath.

Comment: ok sir ill post the whole html for that div

Comment: *when I use it in my code it has some error* What is it? and how do you use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The xpath is close. You need to use `//` at the beginning of the path and remove the `/@src`

```
//li[@class="result-row"]/a[@class="result-image gallery"]/img[@class=""]
```

If you want to make sure the element has `src` attribute it's like that

```
//li[@class="result-row"]/a[@class="result-image gallery"]/img[@class=""][@src]
```

To get the `src` attribute use `get_attribute('src)`

```
src = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class="result-row"]/a[@class="result-image gallery"]/img[@class=""]')[0].get_attribute('src')
```

Note that `find_elements` return list, use index to get the first element.

If you want to use `class="result-info"` to locate the element you can do

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//p[@class="result-info"]/../a[@class="result-image gallery"]/img[@class=""]')
for element in elements:
    src = element.get_attribute('src')
```

Comment: how do I get the image `src` the one that ends with `jpg` file in order for me to save the image or the url in it? I tried to `print(src)` it returns me `
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a1858a5fdf3e236394be883fc8f6bc5a", element="0ab23f0f-5420-498c-bcfd-22af33872247")>`

Comment: i want to get the image attribute `src`

Comment: oh i see, so i  can add another function like `get_attribute` i didint know that. Thanks for the answer sir. Can you explain it to me deeper? why you used index 0 array and other things

Comment: @Vince `get_attribute` is part of Selenium, you don't need to add anything. The index 0 is already explained in the last line.

Comment: it does not give me the correct output sir, instead it gives me only one image url and every letter there is a new line.

Comment: its like this `h
t
t
p
s
:
/
/
i
m
a
g
e`

Comment: @Vince well there is only one `img` in the html you provided and asked about. How do you get the `h t t p s : / / i m a g e`? with print?

Comment: i just want to list all the image url that `result-info` has. In my whole html, there are many `result-info` like its a card

Comment: the url i practiced scraping  is `https://vancouver.craigslist.org/search/ela`

Comment: @Vince The image is not part of `result-info`. Updated my answer.

Comment: ya sir. i already figured it out. Thanks a lot for your answers !!

Answer (score 2):

Actually the xpath has been copied correctly,
You have used it in a wrong way in the fetch code.

If you want the specific image, use

```
image = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sortable-results"]/ul/li[1]/a/img')
```

Or, if you want a list of all images of same xpath type, use:

```
images = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="sortable-results"]/ul/li/a/img')
```

(i.e. remove the specific number of 'li' div or any other div that you want to generalise and use *find_elements*; you need to use *find_element* for fetching a specific single element)

To get the attribute 'src', use *get_attribute* method:

For case 1:

```
website = image.get_attribute('src')
```

For case 2:

```
website = images[0].get_attribute('src')
```

Comment: but i want the image `src` how could i achieve that?

Comment: got me an error `'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'`

Comment: Updated the answer. If you fetch using find_element*s*, it fetches a list. So you need to select the element from list, i.e. list[0] in this case. If you fetched using find_element though, you would need to select from a list and you can directly get attribute

Comment: i dont get the output i want sir. It just gives me one image url but in a different form. like every letter there is a new line. its like this `h
t
t
p
s
:
/
/
i
m
a
g
e
s
.
c
r
a
i
g
s
l
i
s
t
.
o
r
g
/
0
0
R
0
R
_
x
w
4
R
v
C
R
Y
D
B`
I just want to list all the image url in every `result-info`

Comment: I am sure you are printing it wrong. If you want 'src' for all the images fetched in the list, use a loop. Like 'for image in images: website = image.get_attribute('src'); print(website)'

Comment: i just used
`
 images = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="sortable-results"]/ul/li/a/img')
    website = images[0].get_attribute('src')
    for img in website:
      print(img)
`

Comment: You can't use loop for the output. That is why you are getting every alphabet in new line. Use loop for input. Use the code that I provided in my last comment. Also till then, learn more on basic python functionalities such as lists and loops.

Comment: I get it sir. I put in my loop like this `print(img.get_attribute("src"))` and it prints me all the image url's. I thought i could use `find_elements_by_xpath` and concat some function like `get_attribute('src)` and loop and it got me an error. thats why. Thanks sir!

Comment: Exactly, good job. And you're welcome. Also, if you find the answer useful, mark as correct to help others know what worked.

Comment: ok sir I cant mark two correct answers sorry. I just upvoted your answer. The other one gives me the same code i did but thanks a lot for your answer